# Do "empirical" and "imperial" share a common etymology?

Tags: etymology, latin, origin-unknown, roots, lexicon

Nothing more to my question, really. I just wonder if the words share an etymological root. Thanks.

Comment: With all due respect, I fail to understand why this question should be put on hold. Doesn't the website have a whole category for etymology? Your decision seems rather whimsical.

Answer (score 4):

No: *imperial* is from Latin *imperium* "power". *Empirical* is from Greek *empeiros* "experienced", from *peira* "attempt".

Answer (score 4):

**Emperor** is from Latin *imperator*, a commander, from *imperare*, to order. A related word is *imperative* as in the grammatical term *imperative voice*, i.e. the voice in which commands are given.  *"Empire", "emperor"* came from this via Old French.
**Empirical** is from Greek *experienced* by way of Latin *empiricus*: no relation to *imperator*.